# mysql_num_rows() error

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am displaying an editable table in drupal with the following code

```
function _MYMODULE_sql_to_table($sql) { 
  $html = "";    
  // execute sql
  $resource = db_query($sql);    
  // fetch database results in an array
  $results = array();
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($resource)) {

     $results[] = $row;
      $id = $row['id'];
      $email = $row['email'];
      $comment = $row['comment'];
 //     drupal_set_message('Email: '.$email. ' comment: '.$comment. ' id: '.$id);
  }
  // ensure results exist
  if (!count($results)) {
    $html .= "Sorry, no results could be found.";
    return $html;    
  }

  // create an array to contain all table rows
  $rows = array();
  // get a list of column headers
  $columnNames = array_keys($results[0]);

  // loop through results and create table rows
  foreach ($results as $key => $data) {
    // create row data
    $row = array(

    'edit' => l(t('Edit'),"admin/content/test/".$data['id']."/ContactUs", $options=array()),);

    // loop through column names
    foreach ($columnNames as $c) {
      $row[] = array(
        'data' => $data[$c],
        'class' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $c)),
      );
    }

    // add row to rows array
    $rows[] = $row;

  }

  // loop through column names and create headers
  $header = array();
  foreach ($columnNames as $c) {
    $header[] = array(
      'data' => $c,
      'class' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $c)),
    );
  }

  // generate table html
  $html .= theme('table', $header, $rows);

  return $html;

}

// then you can call it in your code...
function _MYMODULE_some_page_callback() {

  $html = "";

  $sql = "select * from {contact3}";

  $html .= _MYMODULE_sql_to_table($sql);

  return $html;
}
```

However, I keep getting the mysql_num_rows() error as

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.  What is causing it?

Comment: when this happens it means the query failed, Check the query related `mysql_num_rows`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Drupal are you using?

try `db_affected_rows()`

or `db_num_rows()`

Comment: I know, the exact error is warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wamp\www\drupal-6.19\includes\database.mysql.inc on line 176.    When I reload the page the error disappears, its there when I submit my form though. What do i need to change? I am assuming I would need to put db_affected_rows somewhere

Comment: It works fine when the 'select' query is run. The mysql_num_row() error comes only when the 'update' query is run. How do i modify it for the 'update' query?